# How to compare the a single value among the comma seperated values in a column of a database using Select Query?

Tags: sql, mysql, normalization

I have a value say for example "1" and I Have column "`grp_id`" in my db table "`tbl_grp`". This column "`grp_id`" contains the commaseperated values as example "`1,2,3`" I am looking for a way to compare my single value with column "`grp_id`".

right now I am using the below query:

```
"SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname FROM tbl_grp WHERE grp_id='1'";
```

Comment: Use a junction table (containing `user_id,grp_id`) not comma separated values.

Comment: @Martin I have a comma separated values in the column I cant change it the way u r suggesting my friend, I have to use the same table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could you [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname FROM tbl_grp WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, grp_id);
```

But the correct way to do this, instead of storing a comma-separated list of ids in a column, is to have a many-to-many association between your users and groups:

```
user(user_id, user_fname, ...)
group(group_id, group_name, ...)
user_group(#user_id, #group_id) // you can have any number of (user_id, group_id) couples
```

Comment: @user576875 Is there any draw back in this solution?

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() or any other solution like this will be slower than a proper database design (as described in the second part of my answer)

Comment: @user576875 I cannot understand the second part of ur answer

Comment: @SomeoneWhoHasDownVoted please provide the reason for down voting the answer.. Why it has been downvoted

Comment: @user* it's called normalisation

Comment: put only 1 id in grp_id; and use multiple rows instead

Comment: By The way I Found it helpful.. Thanks @user576875

Answer (score 3):

Your data is not in First Normal Form.  If you follow the rules for first normal form, you will have keyed access to all data.  Some queries might still result in a table scan, but not this kind.

Don't use CSV for searchable items.  Decompose this field into a 1NF equivalent.

It's not a many-to-many relationship as another answer said.  It's a one-to-many.

Comment: Presumably 1 user can belong to multiple groups and each group has multiple users?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname 
FROM tbl_grp 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', grp_id);
```

Comment: @SomeoneWhoHasDownVoted please provide the reason for down voting the answer.. Why it has been downvoted

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname FROM tbl_grp WHERE grp_id LIKE '1';

try i am no master in db, but best i can suggest this.